# Можно ли хранить много ключей в одном значении в словаре?

Tags: c#, словари

Например:

```
{key1, key2, value1};
{key3, key4, value2}...
```

Также чтобы я мог достать данный ключ

```
myDict.ContainsKey(key1); => true
```

Comment: У вас, получается, какай-то "перевернутый" словарь. Почему бы в таком случае не сделать значение ключом, а ключи - значениями? И проверять `ContainsValue()`?

Comment: [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Можно, кто запретит?

```
myDict.Add(key1, value1);
myDict.Add(key2, value1);
myDict.Add(key3, value2);
myDict.Add(key4, value2);
```

Тут главное понимать какие требования вы предъявляете к словарю, как его используете?

Если вам нужно часто извлекать значение по ключу, то именно так и надо делать, это хорошее правильное решение.